# cannot access drupal admin site

Tags: drupal

I am in the process of moving my drupal site to a new IIS server.  I had it running perfectly on one server.  I disabled all non-core modules, turned off clean urls, put the site in maintenance mode and moved the files and database to my new server.  I am able to bring the new site up fine.  I can view the main page as well as other content.  I can even create new content.
However, whenever I try to access the admin page, I am getting a 500 error on the server.  I am not getting anything in the server logs to indicate what the problem might be.  Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Let me pull out my crystal ball... Well... nothing there.. Are you sure the turning off of the clean urls did not break anything? This is usually not recommended. What is the offending url?

Anyway.. I think this question should rather be on serverfault.

Comment: I apologize - I realize this is a rather vague issue, but I was hoping someone may have seen this problem before and maybe there was quick fix.  I'm not entirely sure that the clean urls were responsible for anything, but I would think that the admin site would be pretty standard - I tried mysite/index.php?q=admin and mysite/admin, but neither worked.  I may end up trying a new fresh install, make sure that works correctly, then attempt to move my existing site over.

thanks

Comment: Is there a redirect happening on admin for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the menu router menu system not rebuilt correctly?

Try getting to the Modules page, Menu page, or run cron.

Comment: I was able to run cron using it's url - /admin/report/run-cron.
Now I am able to access the admin site.


thanks

Comment: sorry - that is /admin/report/status/run-cron

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why you cannot access the administrative pages, including the fact the database tables have not been correctly moved.
Check the content of the table users, and verify the user account for the "super user" (the one with user ID equal to 1) has still the user ID equal to 1. That is a particular user that has automatically any permission; if the user ID is not 1 anymore, then the account becomes a normal user account, and it needs to be expressly allowed to do anything.

Comment: That is all correct - my admin account is at 1 so it should be able to access anything.
I'm not actually being denied access - I can't get anywhere.  It almost seems like it is timing out for just that page.

Comment: Have you tried to access an administrative page using directly its URL  (`/admin/content/node`, in example)?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to disable clean urls, this is how your enable them in IIS:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/505/install-drupal-on-iis/

could be something to do with clean urls, i also had this problem when recently removing my website to IIS, clean url's fixed this issue!